# Onesignal include_external_user_ids not formatting well in send push notification API request

Tags: php, push-notification, onesignal

Someone please help me with using multiple player ids stored in a variable in onesignal.

I have a variable called $onesigId that's holding the following string of values: "2","3","77", "99".
In my onesignal send function I made it an array like this: $onesigId = array($onesigId); but when I send the notification the result shows as below:

```
JSON sent: {"app_id":"my_app_id","headings":{"en":"Amazing Features"},"include_external_user_ids":["\"2\",\"3\",\"77\",\"99\""],"data":{"foo":"bar"},"url":"https:\/\/testurl.com\/help","contents":{"en":"My testing message"}} JSON received: {"allresponses":"{\"id\":\"\",\"recipients\":0,\"errors\":[\"All included players are not subscribed\"]}"}
```

Here's my code below:

```
 $userids = array();
        $tu = 2;
        $on=1;
        $sql = $db -> prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE regTarget=? AND is_active=?');
            $sql -> bind_param('ii', $tu, $on);
            $sql -> execute();
            $result = $sql->get_result();

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
                $userids[]= $row['id'];
                }


                $str = '"' . implode ( '","', $userids ) . '"';

              //echo $str;

                //SEND ONESIGNAL PUSH
                $onesigTitle = "$subject";
                $onesigMessage  = "$message.";

                $onesigId = "$str";

                $onesignalUrl = "$link";

function sendMessage(){
        global $onesigTitle;
        global $onesigMessage;
        global $onesignalUrl;
        global $onesigId;

        $onesigId = array($onesigId);
        $content = array(
            "en" => $onesigMessage
            );

        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => "my_app_id",
            'headings' => array("en" => $onesigTitle),
            'include_external_user_ids' => $onesigId,
            'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
            'url' => $onesignalUrl,
            'contents' => $content
        );


        $fields = json_encode($fields);

        print("\nJSON sent:\n");
        print($fields);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                                   'Authorization: Basic MY KEY HERE'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;


    }

    $response = sendMessage();
    $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    $return = json_encode( $return);

    print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
    print($return);
    print("\n");
```

Note that all the other variables are working as expected, just the $onesigId that's misbehaving.
When I add just a single id, it sends successfully. I want to know why the array("2","3","77", "99") is turning into "\"2\",\"3\",\"77\",\"99\"" in the response and how to fix it.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a php question about how to build an array. This line is taking $onesigId which is a string that contains "2", "3":
        $onesigId = array($onesigId);

This is not how you create an array in php.

Comment: Thanks Gardner. I have included the part where the string "2","3","77", "99" was built. I guess this can help you in helping me find the problem. I actually am getting the ids from my db and I want to put them in array in this format as included in onesignal documentation 'include_external_user_ids' => array("xxx","xxx","xxx", "xxx"),

Comment: Someone please come to my aid. I am still not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by using csv_string_to_array() to convert the string $str to an array and then assign it to the onesigId. Everything looks fine now.

```
$userids = array();
$tu = 2;
$on=1;
$sql = $db -> prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE regTarget=? AND is_active=?');
    $sql -> bind_param('ii', $tu, $on);
    $sql -> execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
        $userids[]= $row['id'];
        }


        $str = '"' . implode ( '","', $userids ) . '"';

         //This is what I used in converting the string to array
         function csv_string_to_array($str){
          $expr="/,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))/";
          $results=preg_split($expr,trim($str));
          return preg_replace("/^\"(.*)\"$/","$1",$results);
          }

      //echo $str;

        //SEND ONESIGNAL PUSH
        $onesigTitle = "$subject";
        $onesigMessage  = "$message.";

        //HERE AM ASSIGNING THE ARRAY TO onesigId
        $onesigId = csv_string_to_array($str);

        $onesignalUrl = "$link";

function sendMessage(){
global $onesigTitle;
global $onesigMessage;
global $onesignalUrl;
global $onesigId;

$content = array(
    "en" => $onesigMessage
    );

$fields = array(
    'app_id' => "my_app_id",
    'headings' => array("en" => $onesigTitle),
    'include_external_user_ids' => $onesigId,
    'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
    'url' => $onesignalUrl,
    'contents' => $content
);


$fields = json_encode($fields);

print("\nJSON sent:\n");
print($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                           'Authorization: Basic MY KEY HERE'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;


}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
```